# Grails 2.0.0 JUnit test @RunWith annotation equivalent

Tags: grails, junit, cucumber, bdd, functional-testing

So my understanding is that the grails testing framework is backed by JUnit tests.

I am trying to hook in cucumber-jvm, and the simplest way appears to be to have a JUnit test with the annotations @RunWith(Cucumber.class) and @Feature(".")

Those annotations appear to be ignored when I build test classes however.  I suspect my groovy test classes aren't exactly picked up as JUnit test cases in the normal way.

Is there any way to get the equivalent of those annotations working in grails?

Comment: could you just use the built in testing harness for grails or use Spock?

Comment: Yes I could, but my preference would be to use cucumber feature files and groovy step definitions using geb to drive the browser, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

I am using Cucumber-JVM and Geb to functionally test some of our internal grails apps, using this grails plugin http://grails.org/plugin/cucumber

So far so good, I haven't used the annotations you mention however.